# How can I change an attribute of every object in a list of objects to the same value? (in python3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

### TL, DR:

#### How can I modify an attribute of all class instances in a list of class instances which are essentially values of a dictionary? Assume I want to assign all attributes to the same value.

---

I did a little search in SO, however could not found a similar question.

I have two classes let's say `Bullet` class, and `Meteor` class.

I get a dictionary(named as `hits`) of collisions between bulletes and meteors in such a form:

```
{<Meteor sprite(in 0 groups)>: [<Bullet sprite(in 0 groups)>, <Bullet sprite(in 0 groups)>]}
```

As you see, apart from my specific example, the situation is that I have a dictionary and the values of that dictionary is a list consisting of the instances of a class.

*What I want to do is, to be able to change the `bottom` attribute of `rect` attribute of all `Bullet objects` of all lists(values of dictionary).* I want to equate it to `-1` for all `Bullet objects`.

#### I know that I can achieve it just by iterating over values and iterating over all elements of values(lists in this case), with nested loops. However, I am almost certain that there exists a more *`pythonic`* way of doing that.

Thanks in advance.

---

For being more clear, I am attaching the code also, though I don't think necessary:

```
hits = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(sprites.meteors, sprites.bullets, True, True)

for meteor in hits:
    hits[meteor][0].rect.bottom = -1
```

Here, by doing this, I am able to modify only **one**(first) `bullet` in each list(value of the dictionary). What I do want to achieve is, to apply that assignment to each element.

Comment: "there exists a more pythonic way of doing that": not really: iterating over the list of values is fine.

Comment: BTW, "class instances" is sort of redundant. *Everything* is a class instance in Python.

Comment: @00 well, that makes me sad

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga what should be the correct use in my case?

Comment: Not really: Python doesn't have complicated data structures, which is what you would need here. While it has convenient shortcuts for some operations, most of the time, Python is a very simple and straightforward language.

Comment: @00 then, the preferred way is to use the simplest approach instead of the shortest(in line count),  right?

Comment: On the Python prompt (`>>>`) try the following: `import this`. Lines 2, 3, 5 and 7 may be interest here.

Comment: @00 wow, cool. Buttt, line 5 states "Flat is better than nested."

Comment: Yes. Perhaps you read that as relating to a (nested) for loop. Alternatively, you could read that as relating to a nested data structure. Your data structure is quite complicated, and as much I would like to (also) be able to just do `hits[:][:].rect.bottom = -1`, that would complicate the language (and interpreter) tremendously. So, arguably, a flat data structure is better than a nested one.

Comment: @00 ok, thanks for the explanations. I have done it as follows: `for mob, bullets in hits.items():
        for bullet in bullets:
            bullet.rect.bottom = -1`